# Java Library: Command Line Option Parser

Tags: java

Anyone know of a library that handles parsing arguements passed from the command line (IE: args[] in public static main).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apache commons-cli.

Answer (score 5):

I've used `jopt-simple` and found it pretty simple. Their webpage lists about 10 other similar libraries...

Answer (score 1):

try `cli-parsec` http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|a%3A%22de.dr1fter.cli-parsec%22
maven dependency (currently latest version):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>de.dr1fter</groupId>
    <artifactId>de.dr1fter.cli-parsec</artifactId>
    <version>0.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

documentation wiki: https://github.com/dr1fter/cli-parsec/wiki/Example

Comment: Based on the domain/URL of your link(s) being the same as, or containing, your user name, you appear to have linked to your own site/a site you're affiliated with. If you do, you *must disclose that it's your site*. If you don't disclose affiliation, it's considered spam. See: [**What signifies "Good" self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212) and [the help center on self-promotion](//stackoverflow.com/help/promotion). Disclosure must be explicit, but doesn't need to be formal. When it's your own *personal* content, it can just be something like "on my site…", "on my blog…", etc.

Answer (score 0):

GNU getopt for Java.
Kinda old but it is a good getopt port from GNU that I have used in the past. It works just like the C version : http://www.urbanophile.com/~arenn/hacking/download.html