# invoking a java application from command line

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java Library: Command Line Option Parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473557/java-library-command-line-option-parser)

I have to build a `Java` application that will be launched with this command line:

```
myapplicationname [–n num] [-x num –y num] [-t] [-a]
```

How can I do this?
I use args[i] to collect the arguments from the command line but I'm looking for other form to do this.

Comment: Maybe you should look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367706/is-there-a-good-command-line-argument-parser-for-java

Comment: @mat some better answer can be given, than just a two words sentence.

Comment: well, I don't even think that the question is duplicate, since @user1884694 is asking how to run the application without the `java -jar` but just as `myapplicationname`, and I provided a valid answer (that somebody kindly downvoted without explaination).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should definitely have a look at [commons-cli](http://commons.apache.org/cli/) to parse your command line parameters. Plus, you need to create a script (bash or batch) to start your app, or in alternative do something similar to this: [Self executing jar files (article from my blog)](http://en.newinstance.it/2012/04/17/self-executing-jar-files/).